# issue on pandas_ta adx indicator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

when i run this code it's obvious get this error s missing close value.

```
df['ADX'] = ta.adx(df['High'], df['Low'],length = 14)
df

output:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-1031ca130ef0> in <module>
----> 1 df['ADX'] = ta.adx(df['High'], df['Low'],length = 14)
      2 df

TypeError: adx() missing 1 required positional argument: 'close'
```

now when give closing value and run

```
df['ADX'] = ta.adx(df['High'], df['Low'],df['Close'],length = 14)
df

output:



`enter code here`ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1
```

if any one know where i am doing wrong please let me know .

this is how i am gettinf dataframe

```
df = get_history(symbol = "BTCUSDT", interval = "1d", start = timestamp)
df
```

Comment: What is ta?  how do I import?

Comment: @scott Boston usually imported like - import pandas_ta as ta

Answer (score 1):

The ADX indicator generates three dataframe columns, which is why there is this exception.
Do this like this:

```
a = ta.adx(df['High'], df['Low'], df['Close'], length = 14)
df = df.join(a)
df
```

you will get three columns with data

> (ADX_14     DMP_14     DMN_14)

and you can remove unnecessary columns with the `drop` function

Comment: What is the difference here to what the other answer suggests?

Comment: I have been working on this for two days!  Thank you for finally solving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import talib

real = talib.ADX(df['High'], df['Low'], df['Close'], timeperiod=14)
print(real)
```

What library do you use to calculate the indicator?

If it doesn't work out, show how you get the data and from where on "BTCUSDT"?

Comment: as wrought in heading it's pandas_ta library .

import pandas_ta as ta

also one thing more when i run other indiactors like :

ema and rsi it works but don't know what wrong with adx

df["EMA"] = ta.ema(df.Close, length = 5, offset=None, append=True)
df

df["RSI"] = ta.rsi(df['Close'], length = 14 ,offset=None, append=True )
df

Comment: Most likely you have something wrong with the 'BTCUSDT' data.
I tried it like this:adx = ta.adx(df['H'], df['L'], df['C'], length = 14). You will have your own data with other column names not H, L, C.
The indicator was calculated without any problems.

Comment: this is how i import data

not able to send code at ones so break kindly join them

def get_history(symbol, interval, start, end = None):
    bars = client.get_historical_klines(symbol = symbol, interval = interval,
                                        start_str = start, end_str = end, limit = 1000)
    df = pd.DataFrame(bars)
    df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,0], unit = "ms")

Comment: df.columns = ["Open Time", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume",
                  "Clos Time", "Quote Asset Volume", "Number of Trades",
                  "Taker Buy Base Asset Volume", "Taker Buy Quote Asset Volume", "Ignore", "Date"]
    df = df[["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"]].copy()
    df.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
    for column in df.columns:
        df[column] = pd.to_numeric(df[column], errors = "coerce")
    
    return df

Comment: For verification, request data from yaho: import pandas_datareader.data as web             df = web.DataReader('^GSPC', 'yahoo', start='2010-05-15', end='2021-10-01')

Comment: i apply no change same error  . aslo as it told you here also getting ema ,rsi  , value but don't know what wrong with adx

Comment: tis is how apply it.: import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import pandas_datareader.data as web 
import pandas_ta as pta
import ta
df = web.DataReader('^GSPC', 'yahoo', start='2010-05-15', end='2021-10-01')
df
 df["EMA"] = pta.ema(df.Close, length = 5, offset=None, append=True)
df  
 df["RSI"] = pta.rsi(df['Close'], length = 14 ,offset=None, append=True )
df
 . till here it works . then adx comes....
 df['ADX'] = pta.adx(df.High, df.Low, df.Close, length = 14)
df

Comment: i try this library too https://technical-analysis-library-in-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/     df['adx']= ta.trend.ADXIndicator(df['High'], df['Low'], df['Close'], window = 14,  fillna = True).adx()
df  it gives this error C:\Users\addev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ta\trend.py:768: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  dip[i] = 100 * (self._dip[i] / self._trs[i])
C:\Users\addev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ta\trend.py:772: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  din[i] = 100 * (self._din[i] / self._trs[i]) but also give out come will you

Comment: please conform it's value from your side .i use btc usdt in this case  2022-03-29 48022.289062 47100.437500 47100.437500 47465.730469 31397059069 47465.730469 46164.469384 22.464082
2022-03-30 47655.148438 46746.210938 47456.898438 47062.664062 29333883962 47062.664062 46463.867610 24.008352
2022-03-31 47512.027344 45390.539062 47062.148438 45538.675781 33327427106 45538.675781 46155.470334 24.247662
2022-04-01 46616.242188 44403.140625 45554.164062 46281.644531 38162644287 46281.644531 46197.528400 23.710718  last one is adx value and second last is ema..

Answer (score 0):

```
df['ADX'] = ta.adx(df['High'], df['Low'],length = 14)['ADX_14']
```

You can run

```
print(ta.adx(df['High'], df['Low'],length = 14))
```